# Prolog convert mins to hours

Tags: recursion, prolog

This is the code I have created.

```
mins_to_hours(In, H, M):-
  In < 60,
  H = 0,
  M is In.
mins_to_hours(In, H, M):-
  In >= 60,
  H is H1+1,
  In1 is In-60,
  mins_to_hours(In1, H1, M).
```

It works fine when the minutes are less than 60, e.g.

```
?- mins_to_hours(20,H,M).
H = 0,
M = 20 ;
false.
```

However when trying to run it for more than 60 minutes

```
?- mins_to_hours(80,H,M).
```

it outputs an exception

```
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [9] _3198 is _3204+1
ERROR:    [8] mins_to_hours(80,_3232,_3234) at c:/.../xyz.pl:11
ERROR:    [7] <user>
```

at the position `H is H1+1,`.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the corrected version of your code.

```
mins_to_hours(Minutes_in, H, M) :-
    mins_to_hours_helper(0, Minutes_in, H, M).

mins_to_hours_helper(H0, M0, H0, M0):-
  M0 < 60, !.
mins_to_hours_helper(H0, M0, H, M):-
  M0 >= 60,
  H1 is H0+1,
  M1 is M0-60,
  mins_to_hours_helper(H1, M1, H, M).
```

The major changes are:

1. To avoid the error message (Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated) since your code is recursive it needs separate incoming and outgoing variables, i.e. `H0` with `H1`, and `M0` with `M1`.
2. To be able to use the additional variables necessities adding a helper predicate, i.e. `mins_to_hours_helper`.
3. The minutes in and the starting minutes variable are actually the same in the helper predicate.
4. Being recursive the code creates choice-points, but the answer is expected to be deterministic. This is solved with a cut (!) in the base case.

Here are some test cases (Uses SWI-Prolog):

```
:- begin_tests(mins_to_hours).

test(-1) :-
    mins_to_hours(-1,H,M),
    assertion(H == 0),
    assertion(M == -1).

test(0) :-
    mins_to_hours(0,H,M),
    assertion(H == 0),
    assertion(M == 0).

test(1) :-
    mins_to_hours(1,H,M),
    assertion(H == 0),
    assertion(M == 1).

test(59) :-
    mins_to_hours(59,H,M),
    assertion(H == 0),
    assertion(M == 59).

test(60) :-
    mins_to_hours(60,H,M),
    assertion(H == 1),
    assertion(M == 0).

test(600) :-
    mins_to_hours(600,H,M),
    assertion(H == 10),
    assertion(M == 0).

test(601) :-
    mins_to_hours(601,H,M),
    assertion(H == 10),
    assertion(M == 1).

:- end_tests(mins_to_hours).
```

To run the test cases:

```
?- run_tests.
% PL-Unit: mins_to_hours ....... done
% All 7 tests passed
true.
```

---

Note: `run_tests.` does not work with [SWISH](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/),

```
No permission to call sandboxed `'$current_module'(_4002,_4004)'
```

so you will have to enter each query manually and manually check the results.

See: [sandbox.pl](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/sandbox.pl)

---

Now for a much better way to do this.

```
mins_to_hours(Minutes_in, H, M) :-
    H is Minutes_in // 60,
    M is Minutes_in rem 60.
```

Notice that this is deterministic, is not recursive, and passes all of the test cases.

See:  [f-///2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%27f-/%27//2) (Integer division) and [rem/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=f((rem)/2)) (Remainder of integer division)

---

Note.

Since you did not specify what should happen when the minutes are negative but did provide code that takes the minutes less than 60 and moves them to the result, this code reproduces that response.

A variation on the code is to use [mod/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=f((mod)/2)) instead of rem/2. This will give a different answer depending upon the input, but might be the desired result.

---

Update based on feedback from @false.

When code is written beyond simple exercises it needs to written with [modes](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=modes) in mind.

The original answer code was written as

Declaration: mins_to_hours(++Minutes_in:int, -H:int, -M:int) is det.

meaning that

Minutes_in has to be bound to an integer
  H          has to be a variable
  M          has to be a variable

however as @false notes

```
?- mins_to_hours(Total, H, 1), Total = 61, H = 1.
false.

Declaration: mins_to_hours(-Minutes_in:int, -H:int, +M:int) is det.

?- Total = 61, H = 1, mins_to_hours(Total, H, 1).
Total = 61,
H = 1.

Declaration: mins_to_hours(+Minutes_in:int, +H:int, +M:int) is det.
```

The first example returns `false`, (fails) but should have returned `true`,
and the second example returns a valid answer for the same values but in a different mode.

While my answer only works in one mode the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54693760/1243762) by Daniel Lyons works with others because it uses constraints.

```
?- mins_to_hours(Total, H, 1), Total = 61, H = 1.
Total = 61,
H = 1.
```

So to avoid the first example by @false from returning `false` which is actually wrong, it should throw an `Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated` error. @false also notes the simplest way to do this is to

> delay unification after the cut

Here is the updated code:

```
mins_to_hours(Minutes_in, H, M) :-
    mins_to_hours_helper(0, Minutes_in, H, M).

mins_to_hours_helper(H0, M0, H1, M1):-
  M0 < 60, !,
  H0 = H1,
  M0 = M1.
mins_to_hours_helper(H0, M0, H, M):-
  M0 >= 60,
  H1 is H0+1,
  M1 is M0-60,
  mins_to_hours_helper(H1, M1, H, M).
```

which passes the test cases

```
?- run_tests.
% PL-Unit: mins_to_hours ....... done
% All 7 tests passed
true.
```

and gives the ERROR for the first example:

```
?- mins_to_hours(Total, H, 1), Total = 61, H = 1.
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [11] _6584<60
ERROR:   [10] mins_to_hours_helper(0,_6612,_6614,1) at c:/XYZ.pl:23
ERROR:    [8] '<meta-call>'(user:(...,...)) <foreign>
ERROR:    [7] <user>
ERROR: 
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
```

Comment: Thanks that is a massive help! :)

Comment: `mins_to_hours(Total, H, 1), Total = 61, H = 1` fails, yet `Total = 61, H = 1, mins_to_hours(Total, H, 1)`, succeeds.

Comment: You are cutting a unification. But cuts only work cleanly with safe arithmetic tests.

Comment: ... or other predicates that produce a clean instantiation error in case of too general goals

Comment: You do not need to handle all different modes. It is sufficient to produce instantiation errors which is quite simple in this case: delay unification **after** the cut.

Comment: In place of `mins_to_hours_helper(H0, M0, H0, M0):-
  M0 < 60, !.` rather write `mins_to_hours_helper(H0, M0, H1, M1):-
  M0 < 60, !, H0 = H1, M0 = M1.`

Comment: Declaration `mins_to_hours(-Minutes_in:int, -H:int, +M:int) is det.` is incorrect. There are many solutions for `M = 23`: `H in 0..sup` are all solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Another version that might be interesting would be one using clpfd:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

min_hours(TotalMinutes, Hours, Minutes) :- 
    [TotalMinutes, Hours] ins 0..sup, 
    Minutes in 0..59, 
    TotalMinutes #= Hours*60 + Minutes.
```

This has the advantage that it works with different instantiations:

```
?- min_hours(600, Hours, Minutes).
Hours = 10,
Minutes = 0.

?- min_hours(TotalHours, 10, 30).
TotalHours = 630.
```

Comment: Is it intended that you use `(in)/2` for all three arguments and not `(#=<)/2` and the like? That is, your solution is perfect whereas comparison predicates have a certain weakness here.

Comment: @false as a fairly new user of clfpd, I'm happy to avoid a pitfall but I can't say I intended to. What sort of weaknesses do they have? I would like to add that to my answer.

Comment: When using `0 #=< Minutes, Minutes #=< 58` &ct, expressions (that is evaluable functors) would be accepted like: `min_hours(0,0,0*0)` succeeds, whereas `min_hours(0,0,M), M = 0*0` fails. You did not fall into this trap. There is a general way out: [`(#)/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd-monotonicity) We still lack a good (prefix) operator declaration for it! One could then write  `#TotalMinutes #= #Hours*60 + #Minutes`

Answer (score 0):

So much code that I am getting dizzy.

For SWI-Prolog:

```
mins_to_hours(Min, H, M) :-
    divmod(Min, 60, H, M).
```

For any Prolog:

```
mins_to_hours(Min, H, M) :-
    H is Min div 60,
    M is Min mod 60.
```