# How to bypass arguments not instantiated on SWI-Prolog online editor?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog-for-sharing

I'm using [SWISH](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/) to write Prolog and I've got a program that converts minutes into hours.

My output for minutes is fine however my hours outputs as `H = 0+1+1` rather than `H = 2`. Is there any way that I can fix this?

I've tried using a `#=` instead of `=` and `is` as someone recommended on another post, but it doesn't work on the online editor and I can't use the desktop one.

```
m2hm(T, H, M):-
    T < 60,
    H = 0,
    M is T.

m2hm(T, H, M):-
    T >= 60,
    T1 is T-60,
    H = H1+1,
    m2hm(T1, H1, M).
```

Comment: Of interest: [Prolog convert mins to hours](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54688256/1243762) - You must be in the same class as this person.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `is` instead of `=`

```
H is H1 +1
```

You did it correctly in the line before with

```
T1 is T-60
```

---

After seeing your comment below,

> if I do that it gives me the error: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

your real problem is not what you asked in the original question.

The answer to `Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated` for this code is answered in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54688256/prolog-convert-mins-to-hours).

Comment: But it didn't work, if I do that it gives me the error:  is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

Comment: @ParadAUX  That is a separate or different question which was answered in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54688256/prolog-convert-mins-to-hours)